# What should I do to be able to click the buttons inside react-router's Link tag, without navigating to that Link?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

```js
<Link to={`/item/${p.id}`}  style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
   <div className="itemContainer">
      <div className="itemContainer__image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${p.pictureUrl})`}}></div>
   <div className="itemContainer__info">
      <span className="item__price">{formatMoney(p.price)}</span>
      <h2 className="item__name">{p.title}</h2>
      <ItemCount initial={1} stock={5} onAdd={onAdd} />
    </div>
   </div>
</Link>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to be able to click on the buttons that I have inside the ItemCount component but keeping the Link on the card at the same time.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for all relevant code? In other words, we should be able to see what `ItemCount` is rendering and doing with any buttons. You may just need to stop the click event from bubbling.

Comment: You may be able to stop the click event propagating, though generally I would suggest rethinking the structure if possible, this is basically the equivalent of wanting a button wrapped in an anchor (Which is invalid HTML)